# Utilizando Ninjet para hacer la injection

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una app windows forms, en la cual trabajo con EF, ninject. Con ninject injecto Interfaz y clase.

```
Bind(typeof(ISaProveedor)).To(typeof(SaProveedor));
```

Mi problema no es ese, estoy ilustrando como trabaja mi app

El problema viene acá, normalmente lo instancio en el constructor de la siguiente manera.

```
private ISaProveedor _repositoryProveedor;


    public frmBusqueda(ISaProveedor repositoryProveedor)
    {
        _repositoryProveedor = repositoryProveedor;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

De esa manera nunca he tenido problemas, el problema se origina cuando sobrecargo el constructor y explicitamente llamo a ese constructor en especifico.

```
private ISaProveedor _repositoryProveedor;


    public frmBusqueda(ISaProveedor repositoryProveedor) : this()
    {
        _repositoryProveedor = repositoryProveedor;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public frmBusqueda(string title, AsignacionTablas t) 
    {
        Titulo = title;
        Table = t;
    }
```

Es aquí el problema llamo a este ultimo constructor y ya no puedo instanciar las variables que estén en el constructor de arriba, que justamente son las variables que utilizo para usar mis métodos que están en mi clase SaProveedor, por lo cual me da error cuando llamo a lo métodos como en este caso.

```
private void BuscarInformacion(AsignacionTablas t)
    {
        switch (t)
        {
            case AsignacionTablas.Proveedor:
                DGVBusquedaDto filter = new DGVBusquedaDto()
                {
                    Descripcion = Helper.InputBoxValor
                };
                **listDGV = _repositoryProveedor.SelectList(filter.Descripcion);**
                dgvBusqueda.DataSource = listDGV;
            break;
            case AsignacionTablas.Producto:
                break;
            case AsignacionTablas.Categoria:
                break;
            case AsignacionTablas.SubCategoria:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Donde dice _repositoryProveedor, el mensaje de error es no esta instanciado y es lógico por que en ningún momento lo hago, gracias al segundo constructor que llamo explicitamente, cuando digo segundo constructor me refiero al que lleva los parámetros tille, AsigancionTablas.

Espero me puedan apoyar.

Comment: ¿Cómo creas la instancia de frmbusqueda?

Answer (score 1):

El otro constructor debería inicializar también la propiedad _repositoryProveedor y para ello debería recibir un parámetro ISaProveedor:

```
public frmBusqueda(ISaProveedor repositoryProveedor) : this()
{
    _repositoryProveedor = repositoryProveedor;
    InitializeComponent();
}

public frmBusqueda(string title, AsignacionTablas t, ISaProveedor repositoryProveedor)
    : this(repositoryProveedor) 
{
    Titulo = title;
    Table = t;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Asier, ya lo solucione utilizando un motor de injección de dependencias